# str.isdigit() doesn't seem to be working in python

Tags: python, password-checker

I'm working on a password checker that checks if the string is a valid password. I have to check if there is at least eight characters, must consist of only letters and digits and the last two characters must be digits.

It all seems to work so far other than the `password.isdigit()`. sometimes the password comes out valid and sometimes it doesn't. Any suggestions?

```
# Gets the users password
password = input('Enter a string for password: ')
# Splices the last two characters of the password
lastTwo = password[-2:]

# Checks the password if it is less than 8 characters
while len(password) < 8:
    print('The password you entered is too short.')
    print()
    password = input('Enter a string for password: ')

    # Checks the password if it is composed of letters and numbers
    while password.isalnum() == False:
        print('Your password has special characters not allowed.')
        print()
        password = input('Enter a string for password: ')

    # Checks the spice to verify they are digits
    while lastTwo.isdigit() == False:
        print('Your last two characters of your password must be digits.')
        print()
        password = input('Enter a string for password: ')

print('Your password is valid.')
```

Comment: What are some inputs that don't act like you expect?

Comment: "Any suggestions" - look for real problems. In *your* code and/or in your understanding.

Comment: You should splice the password for last two characters just before the last loop. Otherwise it will contain the last 2 characters of a previous password

Comment: You never update `lastTwo` after the first time the password is entered - you need to bring it into the `while` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a handful of issues with your provided code. Particularly, you only check the subsequent rules `while len(password) < 8`. If you give it a password of length 10, the rules are never checked. Additionally, you don't update the `lastTwo` with each new password attempted

One way to fix this would be to replace your several `while` statements with `if...elif..elif...else...` wrapped in an overall `while` statement, as follows:

```
# Gets the users password
password = input('Enter a string for password: ')

while True:
    # Checks the password if it is less than 8 characters
    if len(password) < 8:
        print('The password you entered is too short.')
    # Checks the password if it is composed of letters and numbers
    elif not password.isalnum():
        print('Your password has special characters not allowed.')
    # Checks the spice to verify they are digits
    elif not password[:-2].isdigit():
        print('Your last two characters of your password must be digits.')
    else:
        # we only get here when all rules are True
        break

    print()
    password = input('Enter a string for password: ')

print('Your password is valid.')
```

This should work as you intended it. But while we're at it, why not tell the user *every* rule their password has broken? From a UI point of view, it helps to keep the user informed.

If we store an information message alongside whether the relevant rule has been met, we can quickly work out all of the rules that have been broken, like so:

```
valid_password = False

while not valid_password:
    # Get a password
    password = input('\nEnter a string for password: ')
    # applies all checks
    checks = {
        '- end in two digits': password[-2].isdigit(),
        '- not contain any special characters': password.isalnum(),
        '- be over 8 characters long': len(password) > 8
    }
    # if all values in the dictionary are true, the password is valid.
    if all(checks.values()):
        valid_password = True
    # otherwise, return the rules violated
    else:
        print('This password is not valid. Passwords must:\n{}'.format(
            '\n'.join([k for k, v in checks.items() if not v])))

print('Your password is valid.')
```

Comment: Whilst I agree with your sentiment. I doesn't actually answer the (rather poor) question, does it?

Comment: @SiHa you're absolutely right - edited to add in a more direct "fix"

Comment: Thank you. that does make more sense and its much more condensed. I'm still new to python and coding for that matter so I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You never update your value of `lastTwo` inside your while loop. Thus imagine if a user first entered a password `abc123`. Then `lastTwo` would be calculated as `23`.

Now your code would find that the password is too short and prompt the user for a new password. Suppose he enters `abcdefgh`. This now passes your first and second checks. Notice however that `lastTwo` is still `23`, and thus your third check will incorrectly pass.

You should thus recalculate the value of lastTwo whenever you accept a new password or directly check like this:

`while (password[-2:]).isdigit() == False:`

Comment: yeah now that you mentioned that it makes perfect sense and i'm kinda disappointed I didn't realize that. thank you